# AJAX post to php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Although i have followed the sample code from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ and of course Stackoverflow i couldnt find a solution to my problem.

I have a toggle image in html which everytime a user clicks on it,changes the image and update the column in the DB.Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="image" src="smileys/heart.gif" class="play" onclick="toggle(this,'<?php echo $ida;?>')"/>
```

**AJAX**

```
  function toggle(el,al){
        if(el.className=="play")
        {
            el.src='smileys/lol.gif';
            el.className="pause";
    $.post("update.php", { "hr": 1, "ida": al } );

        }
        else if(el.className=="pause")
        {
            el.src='smileys/heart.gif';
            el.className="play";
    $.post("update.php", { "hr": 0, "ida": al } );
        }
        console.log(al);
        return false;
    }
```

**update.php**

```
<?php 
$host       = "localhost";
$user       = "user";
$pass       = "pass";
$database   = "db";

$heart=$_GET["hr"];
$ida=$_GET["ida"];

$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db($database, $con);
mysql_query("UPDATE tablename SET heart='$heart' WHERE id='$ida'");
?>
```

The toggle function works well but the DB is not updated when a user clicks and the image.
I believe it has to do with the `$.post` function,not sending correctly the data to the php.

BTW if i do

```
http://domain.com/update.php?hr=1&ida=127
```

it works.

NOTE: I am using mysql and not PDO only for this example.
...and yes my code is messy and ugly,still learning.
Any help?
Thanks

Comment: "I am using mysql and not PDO only for this example" - And you're doing so in a way that opens up huge security holes.

Comment: "still learning" — Why are you learning the deprecated API instead of a better one that will continue to be well supported?

Comment: meaning i will convert it to PDO when its final.

Comment: Why? That's like building a house on a marsh with the intention of draining the marsh and putting proper foundations in after its built. That's just extra work and more opportunity to leave something unfixed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's a _POST request and not an _GET, so, to capture its values you need to use `$_POST` instead `$_GET`.

Also, as i noticed, there's and _GET link, so you need to change your `$.post` with `$.get`.

Comment: Or change the JS for `$.get` instead of `$.post`

Comment: @wesley - why do you think it works when the OP gives the full link (as described towards the bottom of his question)?